# data type mismatch when comparing dates in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have dates stored in an MS-Access table in the 'General Date' format.

I'm trying to create a query that returns records between a specific date range (all records from March 2010) however I encounter a 'data type mismatch in critera expression' message.

Here is my statement;

```
SELECT Loan.loan_datetimeLeant, product_name, 
      [product_artist/director], product_category, loanItem_cost

FROM Loan 
INNER JOIN ((Product 
INNER JOIN Ite
ON Product.[product_id] = Item.[product_id]) 
INNER JOIN Loan_Items 
ON Item.[item_id] = Loan_Items.[item_id]) 
ON (Loan.[cust_id] = Loan_Items.[cust_id]) 
AND (Loan.[loan_datetimeLeant] = Loan_Items.[loan_datetimeLeant])

WHERE Loan.loan_datetimeLeant >= '01/03/2010' 
AND Loan.loan_datetimeLeant <= '31/03/2010'

ORDER BY Loan.loan_datetimeLeant;
```

I have tried variations on the date format (mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00)

Comment: You are wrong when you say "I have dates stored in an MS-Access table in the 'General Date' format" unless you mean that you are using a text field to store these dates. If the data type is date, then they are stored as doubles, with the integer part indicating the number of days since 12/30/1899, and the decimal part indicating the time of day as a portion of 24 hours. In Jet/ACE SQL, it's important to use an unumbiguous date format or DateSerial() in criteria in order to avoid problems with US vs. non-US date formats. But that's completely independent of the storage.

Answer (score 11):

the delimiter for Access Dates is the #:

```
WHERE Loan.loan_datetimeLeant >= #03/01/2010# AND Loan.loan_datetimeLeant <= #03/31/2010#
```